# Create Superuser in mongo

Tags: mongodb, permissions, database, nosql

I'm trying to create a user in mongo who can do anything in any db.

According to the guide I created a new admin: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/add-user-administrator

This is the code:

```
use admin
db.addUser( { user: "try1",
              pwd: "hello,
              roles: [ "userAdminAnyDatabase" ] } )
```

Then I stopped mongo, enabled the auth and restarted mongo.

Then I tried to create a database with his user.

According with this guide: http://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/how-to-create-database-or-collection-in-mongodb/

```
use fragola 
db.users.save( {username:"fragolino"} )
```

And I get this: "not authorized for insert on fragola.users"

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

The role `userAdminAnyDatabase` gives the user the ability to create users and assign arbitrary roles to them. Because of this, that user has the power to do anything on the database, because he can give anybody any permission (including himself).

However, the `userAdminAnyDatabase` role by itself doesn't allow the user to do anything else besides assigning arbitrary rights to arbitrary users. To actually do something on the database, that user needs to have the following additional roles:

```
readWriteAnyDatabase
dbAdminAnyDatabase
clusterAdmin
```

A user who has the above three rights *and* `userAdminAnyDatabase` is a true super-user and can do anything.

Answer (score 73):

[from docs.mongodb.org-superuser-roles](https://docs.mongodb.org/v2.6/reference/built-in-roles/#superuser-roles)

> Lets write answer that looks simple & also simple to implement

Steps :

1 : `sudo apt-get install mongodb-org`      - *in new terminal*

2 : `sudo mongod --port 27017 --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb`

3 : `mongo --port 27017`      -  *in new terminal*

4 : `use admin`

5 : As @drmirror said a user should have all **4** roles to be **superuser**

### For Mongo Version 2.

```
db.createUser(
{
    user: "tom",
    pwd: "jerry",
    roles: [
              { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" },
              { role: "readWriteAnyDatabase", db: "admin" },
              { role: "dbAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" },
              { role: "clusterAdmin", db: "admin" }
           ]
})
```

### For Mongo Version 3.

```
db.createUser(
   {
       user: "tom", 
       pwd: "jerry", 
       roles:["root"]
   })
```

6 : `sudo /etc/init.d/mongod stop` OR `sudo service mongod stop`    - *in new terminal*

7 : `sudo /etc/init.d/mongod start` OR `sudo service mongod start`

8 : `restart your pc`

9 : `sudo mongod --auth --port 27017 --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb`   -  *in new terminal*

10: `mongo --port 27017 -u "tom" -p "jerry" --authenticationDatabase "admin"`      -  *in new terminal*

**Note** : *step 10 is most important step .*

*it will give Output on terminal like*

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.11
connecting to: 127.0.0.1:27017/test
>
```

Comment: You need to put db and role, like roles:[{role:'root', db:'admin'}]

Comment: @mpoletto If this command is run from within the admin db, the roles array doesn't require a key/value pair to specify the admin db.

Comment: This worked for me, no need to restart the PC though, just the service.

Comment: From version 4.2 you can or even should use function `passwordPrompt()` i.e. something like this: `db.createUser({user:"superuser", pwd:passwordPrompt(), roles:["root"]})`. This is considered more secure than typing password that is visible on the screen. Be careful, password prompt is displayed only once. It does NOT ask you to retype your password.