# Failed to load list of databases

Tags: mongodb, robo3t

I want to connect to a remote database using Robomongo. I can connect to to database but an error says that:
Failed to load list of databases
[image]

What should I do?

Comment: having same problem. It was been working previously but now stopped. "Cannot connect to the MongoDB at xx.xx.xx.xx:443.

Error:
Failed to execute "listdatabases" command."

Comment: I've noticed this happens when I'm using certain versions of the official `mongo` docker images.  Since this error is a permissions thing, it seems like there is some inconsistency with how their images are built when it comes to authentication.

Comment: Had this issue when connecting to Mongo 4.1.6 in docker via Robo 3T. Worked fined with dockerized mongo 3.4.18 though.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

It took me 7 days to figure it out. When I have upgraded to **Robo 3T version 1.3**. it started working just fine. My previous version was **1.2**.

Good to know if you are having this issue.

Comment: This should really, really be upvoted more since this solved everything for me as well. No auth, no nothing, just connect to the exposed port and it worked. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Saving my life in 2020. Thanks!! :)

Comment: This works like a charm! Thank you! This answer should be Accepted and Upwoted!

Comment: my robomongo was 0.9 version because I installed it from the Snap store!

Comment: This answer is from god himself. 
Also, what the actual heck Robo 3T :/

Answer (score 10):

In my experience, it is related to failed database user/password authentication. So probably your IP connection to server is successful but you failed to connect to db. I suggest to double check your database username/password and try again.

And better to show what is inside "Show error details".

Comment: There is not any passwords available! Do I have to set a password?

Comment: Can you also share "Error Details", and which remote database are you using? For example for Mongo Atlas, you should define database user/password.

Comment: No details! only this error! the details says again the same error

Comment: There is error details, you are missing, you should click "Show error details"

Comment: did anyone solve this problem? cause i'm running into the same issue after setting up mongodb on a vps at digital ocean. I can connect remotely, i can connect through ssh tunnel too, but I can't connect normally. The authentication fails, and the details of the error is : "network error while attempting to run command 'buildInfo' ". I've tried everything..

Answer (score 9):

Go to Connection Settings -> Authentication
- Provide Database name, username, password
- Now test the connection
I ran into the same issue, then I provided the above info which solved my issue

Refer: (Vaibhav's post) Point 3.Populate DB name and username and password [How to connect Robomongo to MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28336163/how-to-connect-robomongo-to-mongodb)

Answer (score 5):

I have faced the same problem after updating the MongoDB version from **3.6 to 4.2** and previously I was using the `Robo 3T version 1.2`. So I just updated the `Robo 3T` version from **1.2 to 1.3** and it's started working again.

Answer (score 4):

This is because whatever user you are connecting as does not have the privileges to list the databases.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/built-in-roles/

Note that a user/role can connect and interact with a specific database/collection, but in order for Robomongo to list out the databases/collections, you need to let it connect to your database using a user that has `listDatabases` privileges.

check that your user has read/write & list all Databases privileges.

Comment: u can use this to grant privileges 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22638258/create-superuser-in-mongo

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error ("failed to load a list of databases"). Due to some reason all my databases and collections got removed. Apparently, Robomongo couldn't handle the situation when there are no databases/collections available on the server.

To solve the issue, I connected to Mongo Shell, created a database, and created a collection there:

```
mongo (start mongo shell)
use local (create database named local)
db.createCollection("somename")
```

After that, I could connect to the Mongo server

**Update**: I've faced this issue again, and this time it has been caused by the fact that it was a new Mongo installation on a virtual machine, and connections from other hosts weren't allowed, so I had to modify bindIP from 127.0.0.1 to 0.0.0.0 in /etc/mongod.conf

```
net:
   bindIp: 0.0.0.0
   port: 27017
```

and restart mongo `sudo service mongod restart`

Answer (score 1):

Got the same issue when using mongodb version v4.2.0, but the auth settings don't help. Keep getting the following logs when connecting from Robo 3T(i.e.mongoRobo).

```
2019-09-30T16:41:52.286-0400 I  NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:53862 #1 (1 connection now open)
2019-09-30T16:41:52.286-0400 I  NETWORK  [conn1] received client metadata from 127.0.0.1:53862 conn1: { application: { name: "robo3t" }, driver: { name: "MongoDB Internal Client", version: "3.4.3-10-g865d2fb" }, os: { type: "Darwin", name: "Mac OS X", architecture: "x86_64", version: "17.7.0" } }
2019-09-30T16:41:52.292-0400 E  -        [conn1] Assertion: Location34348: cannot translate opcode 2010 src/mongo/rpc/message.h 120
2019-09-30T16:41:52.292-0400 I  NETWORK  [conn1] DBException handling request, closing client connection: Location34348: cannot translate opcode 2010
2019-09-30T16:41:52.292-0400 I  NETWORK  [conn1] end connection 127.0.0.1:53862 (0 connections now open)
```

Finally resolved it by upgrading Robo 3T to v1.3(mac)

Comment: you can write your solution as an answer, if you have resolved it (and mark it as accepted solution), so that others can see the way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I just found out that I have to upgrade to the latest version that supports latest version of MongoDB. It worked without any authentication.

Comment: This is as well as storagemode11 answer the answer to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when I upgraded mongodb from 3.2 to 5.0 and tried to connect on Robo 3T 1.2.

Then I installed Mongo Compass, issue resolved.  Issue would be resolved installing Robo 3T 1.3 too.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `mongod --auth --dbpath /data/db1` command to start MongoDB, remove `--auth` and start it.

> mongod --dbpath /data/db1

Now Robomongo will be able to connect without authentication. But starting without authentication is not safe. So take another terminal and create a user for your db using `mongo` command as described in this [article](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/).

```
use myDB
db.createUser(
  {
    user: "myUserAdmin",
    pwd: "abc123",
    roles: [ { role: "dbAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" } ]
  }
)
```

Now restart your MongoDB with `--auth`. Connect with Robomongo after configuring above authentication details in its connection settings.

> mongod --auth --dbpath /data/db1

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (using Robomongo), then, I created an user  with his password to connect to the database, and now It is working ok

Answer (score 0):

In my case i changed the configurations of my connection:

You go to: Manager connection >> Edit >> authentication >> rename to database to: admin

when I loaded the my connection all databases appeared.

Answer (score 0):

Start `mongod` process. Start `mongo` process.

On the `mongo` shell you have opened type first `rs.status()` then `rs.initiate()` then `rs.status()`.

Answer (score 0):

My version is 1.4.3 Robo3T.

What worked for me is;

1. Go to MongoDB Connections and edit related connection
2. Go to Connection Settings
3. Under Authentication tab check the "Manually Specify visible
   databases" and fill in the dbName you need to access.

It should fix.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue but it was due to my own mistake. I added replication configuration int the `/etc/mongod.conf` file (i.e replSet name) and restarted the mongod.service without doing an `rs.initiate()`

After doing an `rs.initiate()` and doing a restart of `mongod.service`, my issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

This issue only exists with ROBO3T 1.2 update to a higher version and it will go. The reason behind it is version 1.2 takes authentication but when we don't provide credentials in case of local it does not run listdatabase on startup