# Mongoose connection authentication failed

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

With this help, I created a super user in the mongo shell: [Create Superuser in mongo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22638258/create-superuser-in-mongo)

```
user: "try1"
passw: "hello"
```

In mongo cmd, I have 3 databases: 'admin', 'myDatabase' and 'local'.

Now I try to use this authorized connection to the database called 'myDatabase'.

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://try1:hello@localhost:27017/myDatabase');
```

But this is the error I get:

> name: 'MongoError',
>     message: 'Authentication failed.',
>     ok: 0,
>     errmsg: 'Authentication failed.',
>     code: 18,
>     codeName: 'AuthenticationFailed' }
>   Mongoose disconnected
>   Mongoose disconnected through ${msg}

Comment: So many answers - and most of them are just the same. Most of them are correct but none of them gives any explanation. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63754742/authentication-failure-while-trying-to-save-to-mongodb/63755470#63755470 to get some background information and explanation why it works or not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**THIS ANSWER FOR MONGOOSE 6.7.0! USED IN NUXT 3**

.env PART

```
MONGO_URI = "mongodb://localhost:27017/MyBeautifulDB"
MONGO_USERNAME = "mongoadmin"
MONGO_PASSWORD = "mystrongpassword"
```

DB CONNECTION PART

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

export default async (_nitroApp) => {
const config = useRuntimeConfig();

mongoose.connect(config.MONGO_URI, {
        maxPoolSize: 10,
        authSource: "admin",
        user: config.MONGO_USERNAME,
        pass: config.MONGO_PASSWORD
    })
    .then(() => console.log('Connected to DB'))
    .catch((e) => console.log(e));
}
```

nuxt.config.ts - Register your db connection file to configuration.

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    runtimeConfig: {
        MONGO_URI: process.env.MONGO_URI,
    },

    nitro: {
        plugins: ['@/server/db/index.ts']
    }
})
```

Answer (score 47):

I had the same problem many hours ago, and after all I solve it. My code is:

```
mongoose.createConnection(
  "mongodb://localhost:27017/dbName",
  {
    "auth": {
      "authSource": "admin"
    },
    "user": "admin",
    "pass": "password"
  }
);
```

Comment: Why is mongoose documentation so difficult!? I had tried many variations of these but just did not try this one. Finally you saved my day. Thanks @kartGIS

Comment: what mongoose version are you using?

Comment: thank you for that nice tip!
@Carlos.V I"m using `"mongoose": "^5.9.24"` on `node: 14.6.0`

Comment: For me at least, mongoose version 6.2.4, I would believe all versions >= 6 require the "authSource" without the "auth" parameter. so the "authSource" should be in the main JSON object.

Answer (score 24):

### This is the correct answer now. others are not completely correct.

```
await mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/db", {
    poolSize: 10,
    authSource: "admin",
    user: "admin",
    pass: "password",
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useFindAndModify: false 
});
```

Comment: `authSource admin` did the trick, this is my short version `await mongoose.connect("mongodb://root:example@localhost:27017/example-db?authSource=admin");` Thx

Comment: What happens if you move the user and pass to options, but authsource=admin is in the connection string, and if authSource admin is in options? I am facing the same issue. @asim-imam

Comment: @Omkar, the first case you mentioned didn't work for me. I did that last year maybe I've also tried the second case you said. In my case, I was having trouble connecting admin to the database inside my ubuntu server.

Comment: What issue you're facing?

Answer (score 21):

Further to @kartGIS, I've added one more option to make the connection code perfect as possible.

```
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/databaseName", {
    "auth": { "authSource": "admin" },
    "user": "username",
    "pass": "password",
    "useMongoClient": true
});
```

Comment: can you explain what is this option "auth": { "authSource": "admin" },?

Comment: `"auth": { "authSource": "admin" }` means set `authenticationDatabase` to `admin`.

Answer (score 16):

**Syntax:**

```
await mongoose.connect('mongodb://username:password@host:port/database?authSource=admin');
```

**Example:**

```
await mongoose.connect('mongodb://myUser:myPassword@localhost:27017/myDataBase?authSource=admin');
```

Comment: This worked. I simply added ?authSource=admin and it worked.

Answer (score 11):

### Working fine for me on Mongodb 4.2 and Mongoose 5.7.13

**Node.js**

```
const Connect = async () => {

    let url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/test_db";

    try {

        let client = await Mongoose.connect( url, {
            poolSize: 10,
            authSource: "admin",
            user: "root",
            pass: "root123", 
            useCreateIndex: true,
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            useUnifiedTopology: true
        } );

        log( "Database is connected!" );
    } catch ( error ) {
        log( error.stack );
        process.exit( 1 );
    }

}
Connect();
```

**/etc/mongod.conf**

```
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongo
  journal:
    enabled: true

processManagement:
  fork: true  # fork and run in background
  pidFilePath: /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid  # location of pidfile
  timeZoneInfo: /usr/share/zoneinfo

net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0 

setParameter:
   enableLocalhostAuthBypass: false

security:
  authorization: enabled
```

**Database User**

```
use admin;
db.createUser(
  {
    user: "root",
    pwd: "root123",
    roles: [ { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" }, "readWriteAnyDatabase" ]
  }
)

show users;
{
   "_id": "admin.root",
   "userId": UUID( "5db3aafd-b1fd-4bea-925e-8a4bfb709f22" ),
   "user": "root",
   "db": "admin",
   "roles": [ {
        "role": "userAdminAnyDatabase",
        "db": "admin"
      },
      {
        "role": "readWriteAnyDatabase",
        "db": "admin"
      }
   ],
   "mechanisms": [
       "SCRAM-SHA-1",
       "SCRAM-SHA-256"
   ]
}
```

Comment: For me, just add `user`, `pass` and `authSource: "admin"` and works like a charm. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6):

I have the same problem, and it solved by removing the 'authSource' param

```
/* Not working */
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/test", {
    "auth": { "authSource": "admin" },
    "user": "admin",
    "pass": "admin123",
    "useMongoClient": true
});

/* Working */
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/test", {
    "user": "admin",
    "pass": "admin123",
    "useMongoClient": true
});
```

Tested on Mongoose-v5.0.0.

Answer (score 2):

I got `MongoParseError: credentials must be an object with 'username' and 'password' properties` when used above answers.
Add username password to auth object solved the issue

```js
  try {
    await connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/dbname", {
      auth: { username: "root", password: "example" },
      authSource: "admin",
    });
    console.log("Connected to mongo db");
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error connecting to mongodb", error);
  }
```

mongodb version 5.0.2
mongoose 6.0.4

Answer (score 2):

Respectively, if your `authSource` is the database ('myDB' in the example) itself and you are trying to use the `ConnectionOption` `dbName`, you have to match `authSource`.

```
await mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017,' {
  dbName: 'myDB',
  user: 'myUser',
  pass: 'asldjaskdj'
);
```

Will fail with error:

```
{
    "msg": "Authentication failed",
    "attr": {
        "mechanism": "SCRAM-SHA-1",
        "principalName": "myUser",
        "authenticationDatabase": "admin",
        "client": "...",
        "result": "UserNotFound: Could not find user \"myUser\" for db \"admin\""
    }
}
```

Adding `authSource: 'myDB'` to the connect options will work. Example:

```
await mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017,' {
  dbName: 'myDB',
  authSource: 'myDB',
  user: 'myUser',
  pass: 'asldjaskdj'
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I am using an older MongoDB instance. I simply added `authSource=admin` to the connection string and it solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

According to the latest documentation, it should be like this:

```js
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/databaseName", {
    "user": "username",
    "pass": "password",
    "authSource": "databaseName" // users are scoped to DBs
});
```

Tested on mongoose`6.x.x`

Answer (score 1):

works for me. i use local database, and mongoose ver 6.9.1

.env file:

```
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1:27017
DB_NAME=blabla
DB_USER=blablabla
DB_PWD=blablablabla
```

js file:

```
const DB = `mongodb://${process.env.DB_HOST}/${process.env.DB_NAME}`;

mongoose
  .connect(DB, {
    authSource: 'admin',
    user: process.env.DB_USER,
    pass: process.env.DB_PWD,
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Connected to database.');
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err.message);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

NOTE
This answer is not answering original question but trying to help people in similar situation using NestJS

**NestJS**

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forRoot(
      'mongodb://mongo:27017/test',
      {
        auth: {
          username: 'root',
          password: 'test',
        },
        authSource: 'admin',
      },
    ),
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score -2):

I also faced the same issue but resolved it with this
mongoose.connect(`mongodb://${dbUser}:${dbPwd}@${dbHost}:${dbPort}/userInfo?authSource=admin`). Assuming you have the authentication setup in mongodb.